# Rewrite VBA to be language independent

Tags: excel, vba

I have a script that works fine in my english settings. However this document will be used internationally and needs to work regardeless of language. Could you help me identify the parts of the codes that needs to be rewritten to work?

```
Sub Export()
Dim DataBook As String
Dim ExportBook As String

DataBook = ThisWorkbook.Name

Workbooks.Add
ExportBook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "Options"
Sheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Name = "Models"

Workbooks(DataBook).Activate
Worksheets("OUTPUT_Modeller").ListObjects("Modeller_OUTPUT").Range.Copy
Workbooks(ExportBook).Activate
Worksheets("Models").Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
Worksheets("Models").Activate
    Columns(1).EntireColumn.Delete
    Columns(12).EntireColumn.Delete
    Columns(15).EntireColumn.Delete
    Worksheets("Models").Range("A1:N1").Columns.AutoFit
    Worksheets("Models").Range("A1").Select
  
Workbooks(DataBook).Activate
Worksheets("OUTPUT_Optioner").ListObjects("Optioner_OUTPUT").Range.Copy
Workbooks(ExportBook).Activate
Worksheets("Options").Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
Worksheets("Options").Activate
    Rows(2).EntireRow.Delete
    Columns(1).EntireColumn.Delete
Worksheets("Options").Range("A1:N1").Columns.AutoFit
Worksheets("Options").Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: change language on your computer and see if you are a problem. If u notice one, u can ask precisely

Comment: It looks to me like you only need to change this: `Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "Options"` to this: `Sheets(1).Name = "Options"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only things I can see in your code that depend on language are the sheet names. Note that there are 2 different naming systems for sheets:

1. The tab name of the sheet, which in VBA is `Worksheets("Sheet1")`.
2. The VBA name of the sheet, which in VBA is Sheet1.

The VBA name (green) is changed in the *Properties* window in the VBA editor. And the tab name (red) can be changed in the tab directly.

[image]

So for example instead of using `Worksheets("Options").Range` make sure you give your tab the name in whatever laguage you like eg `alternativ` and the VBA name of the sheet is in English then `Options` like below:

[image]

Then you can use `Options.Range` and no matter what the tab name is translated to it will always refer to the correct tab by its VBA name.